# Given a list, how to find values which are surrounded by smaller values on both sides

Tags: python

Given a list, how to find position of all values which are surrounded by smaller values on both sides.
can we convert it into a numpy/pandas series to use the inbuilt functions from pandas and numpy?

I tried below coding but its not working for all scenario.

```
import ast,sys
import numpy as np
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
maximas=[]
n=len(input_list)-2
for i in range(1,n):
    if input_list[i]>input_list[i-1] and input_list[i]>input_list[i+1]:
        maximas.append(i)
maximas=[int(x) for x in maximas]
print(maximas)
```

it's working for all positive integers like `[3,8,99,9,7,4,3,77,0,2,3,4,5]` `output - [2,7]`- working
but not working for negative numbers like `[-4,-3,-5,-6,-5,-6]` expected `output - [1,4]` - not working
and floating numbers. `[1.5,2.5,3.5,1.5,2.5,7.5,1.5]` expected output - `[2,5]` - not working

Comment: Can you explain your output? Why do you expect`[2,7]` from `[3,8,99,9,7,4,3,77,0,2,3,4,5]` ? Do you want to return indices for such numbers?

Comment: Is it perhaps because you are doing `len(input_list) - 2` instead of `len(input_list) - 1`? Both of your "not working" examples have maximas at the end of the list, but your loop doesn't go that far because `range(1,n)` doesn't include `n`.

Comment: Austin ,yes i want to return indices for such numbers

Comment: Kaya3,Yes you are correct len(input_list) - 1 is working fine ,it's working fine for all scenario.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `zip` along with `enumerate`:

```
[i for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(input_list, input_list[1:], input_list[2:]), 1) if x < y > z]
```

**Example**:

```
input_list = [-4,-3,-5,-6,-5,-6]

print([i for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(input_list, input_list[1:], input_list[2:]), 1) if x < y > z])
# [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `enumerate`:

```
input_list = [-4,-3,-5,-6,-5,-6]
print([i for i, v in enumerate(input_list) if v > input_list[i-1] and v > next(iter(input_list[i+1:]), 0)])
```

Output:

```
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Austin and U10-Forward's answer is very concise, I think that might be not that trivial to read.

I propose the following piece:

```
input_list =[3,8,99,9,7,4,3,77,0,2,3,4,5]
maximas = []
for i in range(1, len(input_list)-1):
    if input_list[i] == max(input_list[i-1:i+2]):
        maximas += [i]
```

it checks from the second element till the second last element whether it is largest among the three numbers with its neighbours. This is easier to read. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Using Numpy functions

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 6, 0, 1])
diff= np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(a)))
list1 = np.where(diff== -2)[0] + 1
print(list1 )
```

Output -

```
[2,5]
```